# JavaScript / typescript: unable to regenerate object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object as specified below:

```
{
"player settings": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "labelName": "site language",
      "labelValue": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "languageName": "ARABIC",
          "language": "لغتك",
          "languageCode": "AE"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "languageName": "CHINESE",
          "language": "你的语言",
          "languageCode": "ZH"
        },
      ],
      "dataType": "DD",
      "selectedData": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "labelName": "subtitle language",
      "labelValue": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "languageName": "ARABIC",
          "language": "لغتك",
          "languageCode": "AE"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "languageName": "CHINESE",
          "language": "你的语言",
          "languageCode": "ZH"
        },

      ],
      "dataType": "DD",
      "selectedData": "1"
    },

  ]
},
{
  "channel": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "labelName": "channel label",
      "dataType": "TX",
      "selectedData": "jhfh"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "others": [
    {
      "id": 16,
      "labelName": "others label",
      "dataType": "TX",
      "selectedData": "dhgdhg"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I modify and re-generate the object with the following conditions:

1. if `dataType` === 'DD' then convert `selectedData` into number.

I wrote the below code but stuck here:

```
for (var j = 0; j < this.myobject.length; j++){
      this.myobject.forEach(obj => {
        console.log(obj)
      });
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps truncate that data dump a little to focus on the important parts? Also show some _before_ and _after_ examples of the data transformation you're after

Comment: one thing is `this.myobject.forEach` should be `this.myobject[i].forEach` ( if this.myobject[i]) is array else there's no need of two loops

Comment: @Phil I reduced the data dump as you said.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `for..in`

```js
let data = {"player settings": [{"id": 1,"labelName": "site language","labelValue": [{"id": 1,"languageName": "ARABIC","language": "لغتك","languageCode": "AE"},{"id": 2,"languageName": "CHINESE","language": "你的语言","languageCode":"ZH"},],"dataType": "DD","selectedData": "2"},],"player settings2": [{"id": 1,"labelName": "site language","labelValue": [{"id": 1,"languageName": "ARABIC","language": "لغتك","languageCode": "AE"},{"id": 2,"languageName": "CHINESE","language": "你的语言","languageCode":"ZH"},],"dataType": "NO DD","selectedData": "2"},]}

for (let key in data) {
  data[key].forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.dataType === "DD") {
      obj.selectedData = +(obj.selectedData || 0)
    }
  })
}

console.log(data)
```

---

Immutable approach

```js
let data = {"player settings": [{"id": 1,"labelName": "site language","labelValue": [{"id": 1,"languageName": "ARABIC","language": "لغتك","languageCode": "AE"},{"id": 2,"languageName": "CHINESE","language": "你的语言","languageCode":"ZH"},],"dataType": "DD","selectedData": "2"},],"player settings2": [{"id": 1,"labelName": "site language","labelValue": [{"id": 1,"languageName": "ARABIC","language": "لغتك","languageCode": "AE"},{"id": 2,"languageName": "CHINESE","language": "你的语言","languageCode":"ZH"},],"dataType": "NO DD","selectedData": "2"},]}

let newObj = {}

for (let key in data) {
  newObj[key] = data[key]
  data[key].forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.dataType === "DD") {
      newObj.selectedData = +(obj.selectedData || 0)
    }
  })
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Mainiac, yes, agree with you

Comment: @CodeManiac I've just modified the data dump with some additional data. Can you please check and update your answer? Because I received an error: `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{ "player settings":`

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara you must be trying to use `forEach` on `key` which not an array, you need to access on value `data[key]` which is an array in given structure

Comment: @CodeManiac posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966534/angular-unable-to-regenerate-array-of-objects for it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use filter on the main obj and then proceed modifying the object.

```js
    function modifyDataToNumber(){
        let myObject = jsonObj['player settings'];
        let ddMyObject = myObject.filter((row)=>(row["dataType"]==="DD"));
        console.log(ddMyObject[0]["selectedData"]);
        ddMyObject.forEach((row,index)=>{
            ddMyObject[index]["selectedData"] = +ddMyObject[index]["selectedData"];
        })

        console.log(jsonObj);
    }
    modifyDataToNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```js
const json = {
  "player settings": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "labelName": "site language",
      "labelValue": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "languageName": "ARABIC",
          "language": "لغتك",
          "languageCode": "AE"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "languageName": "CHINESE",
          "language": "你的语言",
          "languageCode": "ZH"
        },

      ],
      "dataType": "DD",
      "selectedData": "2"
    },

  ]
};


json['player settings'] = json['player settings'].map(setting => {
  if (setting.dataType === 'DD') {
    const updatedSetting = {
      ...setting,
      selectedData: parseInt(setting.selectedData)
    };
    
    return updatedSetting;
  }
  
  return setting;
});

console.log('Result', json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "re-generate", I assume you want an immutable approach to this (that is, generate a copy of the data with the desired changes, rather than changing the original object).

To that, you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let convertSetting = setting => ({
    ...setting,
    selectedData: setting.dataType === "DD"
        ? parseInt(setting.selectedData)
        : setting.selectedData
});

let convert = x => ({
    ...x,
    ["player settings"]: x["player settings"].map(convertSetting)
});
```

Then you can use that function as `convert(yourOriginalObject)`.