# Angular: unable to regenerate array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to modify and re-generate an array of objects.
Please check my created [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tumgfx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Please see the data dump:

```
data  = [
    {
  "player settings": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "labelName": "site language",
      "labelValue": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "languageName": "ARABIC",
          "language": "لغتك",
          "languageCode": "AE"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "languageName": "CHINESE",
          "language": "你的语言",
          "languageCode": "ZH"
        },
      ],
      "dataType": "DD",
      "selectedData": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "labelName": "subtitle language",
      "labelValue": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "languageName": "ARABIC",
          "language": "لغتك",
          "languageCode": "AE"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "languageName": "CHINESE",
          "language": "你的语言",
          "languageCode": "ZH"
        },

      ],
      "dataType": "DD",
      "selectedData": "1"
    },

  ]
},
{
  "channel": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "labelName": "channel label",
      "dataType": "TX",
      "selectedData": "jhfh"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "others": [
    {
      "id": 16,
      "labelName": "others label",
      "dataType": "TX",
      "selectedData": "dhgdhg"
    }
  ]
}
];
```

How can I modify and re-generate the object with the following conditions:

if `dataType` === 'DD' then convert `selectedData` into number.

I wrote the below code but stuck here and got error ERROR
`Error: this.data[key].forEach is not a function`:

```
for (let key in this.data) {
    this.data[key].forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.dataType === "DD") {
        obj.selectedData = +(obj.selectedData || 0)
      }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of the array is an object. And object doesn't have a `forEach()` method. You could try the following function

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.data.forEach(item => {
    for (const key in item) {   // <-- `item.forEach()` won't work because it's an object
      item[key].forEach(subItem => {
        if (subItem.dataType === 'DD') {
          subItem.selectedData = +(subItem.selectedData || 0);
        }
      })
    }
  });
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w68cfg)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
this.data  = [ { "player settings": [ { "id": 1, "labelName": "site language", "labelValue": [ { "id": 1, "languageName": "ARABIC", "language": "لغتك", "languageCode": "AE" }, { "id": 2, "languageName": "CHINESE", "language": "你的语言", "languageCode": "ZH" }, ], "dataType": "DD", "selectedData": "2" }, { "id": 2, "labelName": "subtitle language", "labelValue": [ { "id": 1, "languageName": "ARABIC", "language": "لغتك", "languageCode": "AE" }, { "id": 2, "languageName": "CHINESE", "language": "你的语言", "languageCode": "ZH" }, ], "dataType": "DD", "selectedData": "1" }, ] }, { "channel": [ { "id": 11, "labelName": "channel label", "dataType": "TX", "selectedData": "jhfh" } ] }, { "others": [ { "id": 16, "labelName": "others label", "dataType": "TX", "selectedData": "dhgdhg" } ] } ];

for (let key in this.data) {
    Object.values(this.data[key])[0].forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.dataType === "DD") {
        obj.selectedData = +(obj.selectedData || 0)
      }
    });
 }
 
 console.log(this.data);
```